# User input in D

Tags: io, console, d

I am somewhat new to D, and I am trying to receive user input, like this, with a prompt:

```
string str;
writeln("Enter a string: ");
str = readln;
writeln(str);
```

However, the prompt appears *after* I enter the input; any reason why?

I've trawled the internet for a good hour, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, it's your terminal or whatever you use to see your program's output that doesn't flush stdout. You can force it though:

```
string str;
writeln("Enter a string: ");
stdout.flush;
str = readln;
write(str);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasted so much time on this.

Comment: _"it's your terminal or whatever you use to see your program's output that doesn't flush stdout"_ It's not the terminal. The D file objects keep a buffer of written bytes to avoid needing to make as many system calls for small writes. `file.flush()` writes the file object's buffer to the stream, making it available to the terminal.

Comment: I know very well of the fact that it keeps a buffer and you can flush it manually (obviously as that's what I advised). But most terminals I know ask for the flush themselves on newlines, to the point where I've never ever encountered the described problem myself. I have however seen many people using IDEs having the same problem in other languages. It's not a D problem.

Comment: Yes, I was using the Eclipse IDE.